# Change the options of select box Based on the value of chose on another select box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Consider Two Select Boxes A & B

A has options: `car`, `bike`.

B has options `car1`, `car2`, `bike1`, `bike2`

When `car` is selected Select Box A, then select box B should have only the following options `car1` and `car2`

How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have written yourself to attempt this, as per the FAQ.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i haven't tried it. I need some input on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="vehicle">
    <option>car</option>
    <option>bike</option>
</select>

<select id="vehicle-type">
    <option>--</option>
    <option vehicle="car">car1</option>
    <option vehicle="car">car2</option>
    <option vehicle="bike">bike1</option>
    <option vehicle="bike">bike2</option>
</select>

$(function() {
    $('#vehicle').on('change', function() {
        var vehileType = $('#vehicle').val();

        $('#vehicle-type option').hide();
        $('#vehicle-type option[vehicle="'+vehileType+'"]').show();        
    });
});
```

You can try this JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tt2AD/

Comment: Even simply selecting `car`, selecting `car1` and then switching the first checkbox to `bike` doesn't work in Chome 40 - it leaves `car1` selected in the second dropdown